# How to make stylus not control the mouse?

Tags: windows, mouse, wacom

I want to separate the stylus position from the mouse position in a win32 application. I'm using the wintab sdk and I've seen articles about distinguishing between mousebuttondown/up events coming from the pen/eraser or mouse. But I haven't been able to find anything that lets you use the stylus as a second device.  I want to respond to WT_PACKET events to determine the position of the pen for painting, and use the mouse cursor for other operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

LOGCONTEXT lc;

lc.lcOptions |= CXO_SYSTEM // this flag links it to the system cursor.

return WTOpen(hWnd, &lc, TRUE;

.....